Our API access is currently restricted. Can you please view the required actions and respond accordingly to restore access?
I have checked this condition.

I checked and verified the privacy policy URL, terms and conditions
URL and account delete step URL.
Deleted and recreated the app configuration, then checked again.


Issue message -
Platform Term 7.d
Platform Term 7.d - App Settings Platform URLs are broken
During regular review of apps on the Meta for Developers platform, we found that one or more of the Platform URLs listed in App Settings returns an error. This violates Platform Term 7.d.
To resolve this violation, and app admin must complete these steps:
Check that the URLs and App Store IDs listed for the Platforms selected in App Settings are up to date and functional. For an overview of these platforms, visit Platform Settings.
Test your URLs for errors using Meta’s Sharing Debugger. Look for valid codes 200–299 in the “Response Code'' field. Violating codes are 100–199, 300–299, 400–499, 500–599.
Allowlist the IP addresses (most secure) or the user agent strings used by Meta’s URL crawler.
If you don't take action to resolve this issue before the due date, your app will be deactivated. Your app will not be reinstated until we confirm that the violation is resolved.

Customer service questions are off topic on [so]. We are not Facebook. We can't do anything about your access. You need to talk to Facebook
